# How do I use keyboard tab navigation in reverse?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, accessibility

When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> on my keyboard, it navigates forwards through page elements. How can I navigate through page elements backwards?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Shift+tab should do the trick.

Comment: It also works in Alt-tab to cycle backwards through tabs.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW - yes. you are right

Comment: Also, in Firefox, you can press Ctrl+tab to cycle through tabs. Ctrl+shift+tab goes backwards too.

Comment: Seems universal... works in Kate 19.12.3 in 2021